# Nested composite components: parent tries to get children attributes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, attributes, nested, composite

On one side, I have a primefaces dataTable in a custom composite component (ListaPaginadaComposite), and in its columns, users can add whatever they want.

On the other side, I have another custom composite component (ListaValoresComposite) that I insert into one of the first component's columns.

It's alright, more or less, but when parent composite refreshes itself, I get `PropertyNotFoundException`, since it's trying to get child attribute ('child') in itself. I'm getting mad trying to solve this, does anyone know how to make myfaces resolve `#{cc}` correctly, parent or child, and not always resolve to parent? The Location of the ValueExpression points to the correct xhtml (listaValores.xhtml), but #{cc} is always resolved to ListaPaginadaComposite.

I'm working with Primefaces 6.1 and Myfaces 2.2.12.

```
13/06/2017 14:38:00,551 [ERROR] (componentes.application.AtlasAjaxExceptionHandler.logException) - AtlasAjaxExceptionHandler: Se ha producido un error procesando un petición AJAX de JSF. La página '/errorInfo' será mostrada.
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'child' no hallada en el tipo atlas.componentes.composite.ListaPaginadaComposite
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:290)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:377)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
        at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.LocationValueExpression.getValue(LocationValueExpression.java:127)
        at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:360)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:2135)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:764)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:571)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:564)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:323)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:301)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:269)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1458)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1458)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1458)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:262)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1451)
        at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor.processValidators(CellEditor.java:86)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1458)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:382)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:366)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:328)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:301)
        at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processValidators(DataTable.java:844)
        at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:788)
        at org.richfaces.context.MetaComponentProcessingVisitCallback.visit(MetaComponentProcessingVisitCallback.java:73)
        at org.richfaces.context.BaseExtendedVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(BaseExtendedVisitContext.java:103)
        at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedExecuteVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(ExtendedExecuteVisitContext.java:55)
        at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
...
```

Comment: What does it mean, `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'child' no hallada en el tipo atlas.componentes.composite.ListaPaginadaComposite`?

Comment: `"javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Poperty 'child' not found on type atlas.componentes.composite.ListaPaginadaComposite"`

It means it's looking for the property `child` that belongs to `listaValores` (declared as `#{cc.child.column}`) but in 'listaPaginada', that is, the parent composite instead of the correct one.

`<my:listaPaginada>
        <my:listaValores  />
    </my:listaPaginada>`

I don't know how to format code in answers..